# Python watch-dog script : load url asynchronously

Tags: python, linux, networking, asynchronous

I have simple Python script which do check few urls :

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url))
```

as i have socket timeout setted on 5 seconds sometimes is bothering to wait 5sec * number of urls on results.

Is there any easy standartized way how to run those url checks asynchronously without big overhead. Script must use standart python components on vanilla ubuntu distribution (no additional installations).

Any ideas ?

Comment: You could write something with `threading`, but I would personally use [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote something called [multibench](https://svn.upfronthosting.co.za/svn/izak/benchtools/multibench.py) a long time ago. I used it for almost the same thing you want to do here, which was to call multiple concurrent instances of wget and see how long it takes to complete. It is a crude load testing and performance monitoring tool. You will need to adapt this somewhat, because this runs the same command n times.

Answer (score 0):

Install additional software.  It's a waste of time you re-invent something just because of some packaging decisions made by someone else.